# Changing legend on leaflet map based on overlayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, overlay

I`m using leaflet.js library to create multiple maps based on statistical data. Each map displays a different range of values so it would be nice to change legend when user change map.

I found a similar example in this question, but I need to switch between more than two layers. I try simply add more "if" statements and logical operators in code, but it doesn`t work right

`````
var overlays = {
        "threats":threats,
        "impact ":impact,
        "blockages":blockages
    }; 
var basemaps = {
        "OpenStreetMap":osmlayer
    };

L.control.layers(overlays,basemaps,{position:'topright'}).addTo(map);

var threats_legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
var impact_legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
var blockage_legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});


threats_legend.onAdd = function (map) {
var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
div.innerHTML +=
'<img src="./three.png" alt="legend" width="134" height="147">';
return div;
};

threats_legend.addTo(map);

impact_legend.onAdd = function (map) {
var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML +=
    '<img src="./one.png" alt="legend" width="134" height="147">';
return div;
};

impact_legend.addTo(map);

blockage_legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        div.innerHTML +=
        '<img src="./two.png" alt="legend" width="134" height="147">';
    return div;
    };
    blockage_legend.addTo(map); 

map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
    // Switch to the Population legend...
    if (eventLayer.name === 'threats') {
        this.removeControl(impact_legend);
        this.removeControl(blockage_legend);
        threats_legend.addTo(this);
    } 

    else if(eventLayer.name === 'blockages') { 
        this.removeControl(impact_legend);
        this.removeControl(threats_legend);
        blockage_legend.addTo(this);
    }
    else if(eventLayer.name === 'impact'){ 
        this.removeControl(threats_legend);
        this.removeControl(blockage_legend);
        impact_legend.addTo(this);
    }
}); ````
`````

Comment: It would be great if you can add code too. It's hard to understand the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does it mean "_it doesn`t work right_" in your case?

Comment: when i change layers the legend does not change...